# Bash/Shell use find to search after a name, while reading the name line by line out of a file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

So I am struggling with a problem and I can't really figure it out. I have a SH Script, which (in theory) should open a TXT File, iterate over the content (several lines, with only 1 word per line) and execute a find command with the name as parameter, where the name is the word extracted out of the TXT File. I have written the following code, which of course is not working properly, and I can't really figure out why it does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash
home=$HOME
to_process=$home/to_process
solved=$home/solved

while IFS= read -r content_file
do
        echo $content_file
        echo $to_process
        echo "___________________________________"
        for i in $(find $to_process -name $content_file);do
            echo $i
            #cp $i $solved;
        done
done < list_of_files.txt
echo "__Problem solved__"
```

The echo works perfectly and it shows the exact values I need. When going into the FOR, I have zero results. As it can be seen, between the word and the previous path, we have an empty row, where we should have had the value of "$f".

```
'*WORD1_*'
/home/devserv1/to_process
___________________________________
'*WORD2_*'
/home/devserv1/to_process
___________________________________
'*WORD3_*'
/home/devserv1/to_process
___________________________________
'*WORD4_*'
/home/devserv1/to_process

__Problem solved__
```

Might it be because within my TXT File, I am saving the name with quote and *? I do not know how the files are named all the time, so thereafter I only have the first 4-5 characters. Thereafter, I saved them as ' * WORD4_ * ' (in file, there is no empty space between ' and * and the text) in my TXT File, to use it faster in my FIND command. If so, how might I work around this issue?

Comment: yes, my bad. I will correct the typo

Comment: Remove the single quotes in your text file and double quote the variable expansions in your find command: `find "$to_process" -name "$content_file"`.

Comment: Note that `for i in $(find ...)` is not safe. If some of your file names contain spaces they will be split. It would be better to use another while loop: `while IFS= read -r i; do ... done < <(find ...)`. Or, if your file names can also contain newline characters: `while IFS= read -d '' -r i; do ... done < <(find ... -print0)`.

Comment: Thank you @RenaudPacalet :) It worked exactly as I was expecting it to work. And thank you for your note as well. I used another while loop instead of the for.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs has a section on doing this with `find`... 
It basically says *don't*. See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

Abstract a little. Try `globstar`.

```
cat list_of_files.txt
WORD1_
WORD2_
WORD3_
WORD4_
```

I don't particularly like `read` for this.
Personally, with this list, I'd prefer

```
(shopt -s globstar; cp "$HOME"/to_process/**/*WORD[1234]_* "$HOME/solved/")
```

But I assume your list isn't actually that easy. If it's at least not riddled with embedded newlines and worse, maybe this?

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar      
mapfile -t keys < list_of_files.txt
set -x                 
for k in "${keys[@]}"; do cp "$HOME"/to_process/**/*"$k"* "$HOME/solved/"; done
```

(This will still work with embedded spaces and such.)

If you have anything really *odd* in those strings, then be sure to check the `mapfile` documentation.